# Java, cannot receive data from different class file

Tags: java

I created a user interface that can send some data to a function. However, i encountered some errors along the way. I will explain in details some of my coding. First of all, my function would be called, and some data will be send to another class file.

This is my user interface code( I have checked it and it works fine)

```
private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
int x1 = 0;
int x2 = 0;                                     
test.sbutton(x1, x2);}
```

Next, the sbutton function original from my start.java file. It will call a timer function within.

```
public class Start {
Timer timer = new Timer();
   public void sbutton(final int x1, final int x2) {
          timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Cost() {
                public void active() {
                        super.run(x1, x2);
                         new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                   public void run() }{ //some function
          }).start();
 }
 }, 1*1000, 30*1000);
```

The cost.class function code is suppose to receive the x1 and x2.

```
public class Cost extends TimerTask{

// @Override
public void run(int x1, int x2) {
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Integer hour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
Integer min = rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

if (hour== x1 && min == x2) {}
```

However, I received an error message and cannot compile. My error message was " Cost is not an abstract and does not overwrite abstract method run()" Could someone identify the error, I have been stuck here for more than 4 hours. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you extend TimerTask u most provide implementation for the run() method which takes no arguments. U've added two arguments x1 and x2...

Comment: x1 and x2 was added because I want to feed run() with values, so that this data can be send to Cost.run()

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to redefine the Cost class inside your Start class, which isn't allowed.  You can try

```
Cost myArgument = new Cost();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myArgument);
```

assuming that Cost extends the right class to be an acceptable argument.  If you need to pass x1 and x2, define a constructor for Cost to make it

```
Cost myArgument = new Cost(x1,x2);
```

Comment: I think it is the wrong answer. Obviously, the abstract run() method of TimerTask must be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error is from the fact Cost is extending TimerTask and it does not override all of TimerTask's abstract method.  In this case, that is the run method.

To correct the compile error you need to either make Cost abstract:

```
public abstract Cost extends TimerTask {
...
```

or implement the method:

```
public Cost extends TimerTask {

  @Override
  public void run() { // no arguments
     // your own run code
  }
...
```

Now, to pass the x1 and x2 values to a Cost object depends on the approach taken above.  If you want to use the abstract Cost class, you can use an anonymous subclass that overrides the run method and use the x1, x2 values:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Cost() {
    public void run() {
      // call your existing run(x1, x2) method
      run(x1, x2);
    }
},  1 * 1000, 30 * 1000);
```

If you choose to implement the run method in Cost directly, provide a constructor on Cost to receive the values and use them later when the run method is invoked by the scheduler

```
public Cost extends TimerTask {
  private final int x1;
  private final int x2;

  public Cost(int x1, x2) {
      super();
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.x2 = x2;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
      // call your existing run(x1, x2) method
      run(x1, x2);
  }
  ...
```

With this approach, scheduling becomes:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Cost(x1, x2),  1 * 1000, 30 * 1000);
```

Comment: I still have the abstract error when i put run (x1,x2)? I tried leaving the argument of run empty, but the threading don't see to work

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run()} does not seem to run when I chose to use the second method

Comment: @Eugene you should not need the Thread anonymous inner class.  Once you have scheduled the Cost task with the Timer, it is the Timer's responsibility to call the Cost#run() method at the prescribed times.  You do not need to create a separated thread to start or operate the timer.

Comment: @Eugene to clear things up rename your original run(x1, x2) method to doRun(x1, x2).  Then your cost class should implement the TimerTask#run() method as such:  public void run() {  doRun(x1, x2); }

Answer (score 0):

TimerTask is a Runnable, meaning that you need to implement the abstract method `void run()`.
The run method in your code has the wrong signature.